# What needs to be changed in this code to make the page on top of it that loads this in a iframe change load a new url?

Tags: iframe, cookies, parent

ok so heres my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<script>
<!--
/* 
Cookie Redirect. Written by PerlScriptsJavaScripts.com
Copyright http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com 
Free and commercial Perl and JavaScripts     
*/

// page to go to if cookie exists
go_to = "http://www.cookieisthere.com";

// number of days cookie lives for
num_days = 365;
function ged(noDays){
    var today = new Date();
    var expr = new Date(today.getTime() + noDays*24*60*60*1000);
    return  expr.toGMTString();
}

function readCookie(cookieName){
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
    if (start == -1){ 

    } else {
        window.location = go_to;
    }
}

readCookie("seenit");
// -->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This page will load on a page through a iframe... if the cookie is their i want the parent window to go to http://www.cookieisthere.com not the original page. After reading up on it a bit some people say use _top where the link is but i dont know how to do this. All help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<script>
<!--
/* 
Cookie Redirect. Written by PerlScriptsJavaScripts.com
Copyright http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com 
Free and commercial Perl and JavaScripts     
*/

// page to go to if cookie exists
go_to = "http://www.cookieisthere.com";

// number of days cookie lives for
num_days = 365;
function ged(noDays){
    var today = new Date();
    var expr = new Date(today.getTime() + noDays*24*60*60*1000);
    return  expr.toGMTString();
}

function readCookie(cookieName){
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
    if (start == -1){ 

    } else {
        window.top.location = go_to;
    }
}

readCookie("seenit");
// -->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean so cookieisthere.com opens in the parent window... where do i add the _top code?

Comment: Use the new code I gave you. It should go to the top. That's all I changed